# submenu on context menuitem in vscode extensions

Tags: vscode-extensions, submenu

i see a lot of github issues that seem to indicate that the ability to add a submenu that drops down when we click on a custom context menu item, say in explorer/context, was added in Sep 2020, but i can't find it in the extensions documentation.
can someone point me to that?
Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "scm/title": [
        {
          "command": "git.commit",
          "group": "navigation"
        },
        {
          "submenu": "git.stage",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ],
      "git.stage": [
        {
          "command": "git.stageAll",
          "group": "navigation"
        },
        {
          "command": "git.stageUntracked",
          "group": "navigation"
        }
      ]
    },
    "submenus": [
      {
        "id": "git.stage",
        "label": "Stage",
        "icon": "$(something)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100172#issuecomment-645203070

Comment: Is it possible to add submenu dynamically/programmatically during the extension is running?

Comment: I found it helpful to look at the official git extension's package.json for a complete example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/3c3ba581e53962a82294256d239980e8e4b81051/extensions/git/package.json

Comment: Additionally, here's a git diff of what I had to do put my extension's menu items in a submenu: https://github.com/Christopher-Hayes/vscode-chatgpt-reborn/commit/258874442a3ab00189f928f6f4d50f2cd33dd9ec I found the syntax a little confusing, `git.stage` is just a name you make up, move your context menu items into that object, add "submenus" with at least a single item, and add a new item to the context menu object for the submenu.