# How to place a command into a submenu using the vscode extension api

Tags: typescript, command, vscode-extensions, submenu

### I am creating a Visual studio code extension, and I would like to place a command into a submenu like this[image]

here, the "Peek" submenu contains commands like "Peek Call Hierarchy".

Currently in my `Package.json`, I have

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [{
            "command":"myExtension.dothing",
            "title":"make the extension do a thing",
            "category":"myextensioncategory"
        }],
        "menus": [{
            "explorer/context": [{
                    "command": "myExtension.dothing",
                    "group": "myextension.myGroup",
                    "when": "!explorerResourceIsFolder"
                },
                {
                    "submenu": "myextensionsubmenu",
                    "group": "myextension.myGroup"
                }
            ]
        }],
        "submenus": [{
            "label": "my extension",
            "id": "myextensionsubmenu"
        }]
    }
}
```

(not relevant parts removed)

And it shows up with something like this

[image]

I would like to place the "make the extension do a thing" command into the "my extension" submenu, but I don't understand how I would do that from the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.submenus)
Can anyone explain or point me to a resource/tutorial?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand the structure of submenus, you have to add the relevant entries in the menus array.

Your *package.json* may look like this:

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [{
            "command":"myExtension.dothing",
            "title":"make the extension do a thing",
            "category":"myextensioncategory"
        }],
        "menus": [{
            "explorer/context": [{
                    "command": "myExtension.dothing",
                    "group": "myextension.myGroup",
                    "when": "!explorerResourceIsFolder"
                },
                {
                    "submenu": "myextensionsubmenu",
                    "group": "myextension.myGroup"
                }
            ],
            "myextensionsubmenu":[
                  {
                    "command":"myExtension.dothing",
                    "group":"myExtension.myGroup"
                   }
            ]
        }],
        "submenus": [{
            "label": "The Label for the menu that opens the submenu",
            "id": "myextensionsubmenu"
        }]
    }
}
```

The objects in "submenus" array seem to only define the label of the corresponding entries.

You may also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682799/submenu-on-context-menuitem-in-vscode-extensions). It may help you.

Comment: Is it possible to add submenu dynamically/programmatically during the extension is running?

Comment: @Kaviarasu As far as I am informed, that is not possible